# kde plasma no feedback on sound/brightness popups

Tags: kde, plasma-5

when i change my brightness or sound volume, there appears a popup, but i'd like to have some feedback on that popup.
Is it possible to have a slider or some percentage appear as well like in unity on Ubuntu?

im using Kubuntu 16.04 with KDE plasma 5.5.5 with some custom themes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Kubuntu 16.04 with the standard Breeze themes (Light and Dark). But I have also enable `kubuntu-backports` as described in https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/72006-Latest-round-of-backports-PPA-updates-include-Plasma-5-10-2-for-Zesty-17-04?p=401636&viewfull=1#post401636.

As you can see from the attached images, brightness does have a slider and the volume control has both a slider and percentage.

[image: Brightness with slider]

[image: Volume]

Comment: it didnt change anything